# `using` declaration for a user-defined literal operator

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-keyword, using, user-defined-literals

Is it possible to have a `using` declaration for the literals operator, `operator ""`?

E.g.,

```
#include <chrono>

namespace MyNamespace
{
  constexpr std::chrono::hours operator "" _hr(unsigned long long n){
    return std::chrono::hours{n};
  }

  // ... other stuff in the namespace ...
}

using MyNamespace::operator"";    // DOES NOT COMPILE!

int main()
{
  auto foo = 37_hr;
}
```

My work-around has been to put these operators in their own nested namespace called `literals`, which allows `using namespace MyNamespace::literals;`, but this seems somewhat inelegant, and I don't see why the `using` directive can't be used for `operator` functions in the same way as it can for any other functions or types within a namespace.

Comment: `using MyNamespace::operator""_hr;`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That, my friend, is an answer. (A correct answer, even!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using MyNamespace::operator""_hr;
//                           ^^^
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8cecd40a8bc6f0e)

Grammar reference:

> ```
> using-declaration:
>    using typename (opt) nested-name-specifier unqualified-id ;
>    using :: unqualified-id ;
>
> unqualified-id:
>    identifier
>    operator-function-id
>    conversion-function-id
>    literal-operator-id
>    ~ class-name
>    ~ decltype-specifier
>    template-id
>
> literal-operator-id:
>    operator string-literal identifier
>    operator user-defined-string-literal
> ```

Comment: So `user-defined-string-literal` is the syntax element corresponding to `""_hr`?

Comment: @KyleStrand yes, `user-defined-string-literal` is the same as `string-literal identifier` which are `""` and `_hr` respectively